# How to invoke C executable file using Python

Tags: python, c

I have a compiled binary for Linked list written in c. I placed the executable in /usr/bin/ as /usr/bin/app where app is the name of the executable. This was compiled using gcc.

Can anyone help me to invoke this (app) using a python script.

I have written a script below to do this but seems to give errors. I am very new to python and have very basic knowledge on this. I am just exploring pythons features.

Below is the script code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['\usr\bin\app'],
                            stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                        )

(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print out
```

Here are the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./LinkedList.py", line 7, in <module>
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Thank you for your assistancce

Comment: Use forward slash: `'/usr/bin/app'`

Comment: `'\usr\bin\app'` --> `\usinpp`, as falsetru mentioned use forward slashes.

Comment: +1 perfect (tagging + effort) in your first question.

Comment: you may use ctypes for directly using your linked list library with python, or may use cpython to invoke python from the other side
i wrote an article on this topic, you may like it
http://www.huseyinalb.com/2013/04/10/using-python-and-c-together/

Answer (score 3):

Per Comments the answer was:

Use forward slashes `'/usr/bin/app'`

Personally though I would strongly consider using `os.path.join`  or `str.join` and `os.sep` so you don't have to remember which way the slashes should go.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html
http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html